# Can we add two columns while doing PIVOT table in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

**I have a table with 3 columns. in which i am showing Time wise report of ContainerCount with Time.**
**Below image shows the actual table**
[image]

**I am doing pivot for this table and the image is shown below**
[image]

**now i want to add all columns and want to shown in single column. But not getting. The query is mentioned below**

```
SELECT 'CFS to Zero' Location, sum( [0]+[1]+[2]+[3])  FROM                         
(SELECT  [ContainerCount],Time FROM #tt )as Tab1                        
PIVOT                        
(                        
MAX([ContainerCount]) FOR Time IN ([0])) AS Tab2 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `coalesce()`

```
SELECT 'CFS to Zero' Location, coalesce([0],0)+coalesce([1],0)+coalesce([2],0)+coalesce([3],0)  FROM                         
(SELECT  [ContainerCount],Time FROM #tt )as Tab1                        
PIVOT                        
(                        
MAX([ContainerCount]) FOR Time IN ([0],[1],[2],[3])) AS Tab2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need 1 SUM then you don't really need a PIVOT.

Just aggregate and get the MAX values, then SUM them.

This has the benefit that you can just use a BETWEEN to only select a range of Time.
Instead of having to hardcode the Time values in a PIVOT.

```
SELECT 
 'CFS to Zero' AS Location, 
 SUM(MaxContainerCount) AS TotalMaxContainerCount
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   [Time], 
   MAX(ContainerCount) AS MaxContainerCount
  FROM #tt
  WHERE [Time] BETWEEN 0 AND 3
  GROUP BY [Time]
) q
```